# How to link a list from a subsite to the parent site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, web-part

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 site and have a requirement to have a Discussion list on the main site and be able to put that same Discussion list on its sub sites.

The sub site's Discussion list would  be filtered on a column that associates it to that sub site.  I can get the Discussion list web part on the page, however the links and reply always throws an error.

The error states the link can’t be found.  It appears the link is pointing to the sub site for its direction instead of the parent site.  I have tried several ways to accomplish this but they have all ended the same way in error.

Comment: Could you check first [How to show the list from parent site to subsite](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/) then check if you got the same error or not?

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, How do filtered on a column that associates it to that sub site?

Answer (score 1):

Publish to site gallery (requires same site collection)

http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites

Comment: I think the question is about having the content available in both sites. Your approach will create a separate instance of the list, with a different set of responses (data).

Comment: How do filtered on a column that associates it to that sub site?

Comment: @ChrisRomp Perhaps, but synchronized lists are as good as in terms of functionality in my view. I'm not sure how else you would achieve this (even calling any data through rest would require a lot of manual formatting which seems beyond the scope the OP intended. Besides all the modular, permission based structure of SharePoint is likely to cause some issues, although it should be noted that the permissions plays an important role here, as subsite users may be able to cause changes to the list items on the parent site which they have no permissions for.

Comment: @Sai This is probably better asked in another question, but using different views on each subsite would be my recommended OOTB approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2013 and i can reproduce the issue, I can get the Discussion list web part on the page in subsite, however the links and reply always throws an error.

The error states the link can’t be found. It appears the link is pointing to the sub site for its direction instead of the parent site.

You said that "The sub site's Discussion list would be filtered on a column that associates it to that sub site", to modify the existing Flat/Subject/Threaded View in Discussion Board, refer to the following article about how to modify the existing Flat/Subject/Threaded View in Discussion Board of SharePoint 2013:

http://sabinatechdiary.blogspot.sg/2015/08/how-to-modify-existing.html